# Oracle 19C Query with hierarchical JSON

Tags: json, oracle

I have 2 Oracle tables

```
table_1: 
ID   target_id   name   url
1    A           John   example.org
2    B           Jane   helloworld.com

table_2:
id1   target_id   col1   col2
X     A           aaa    bbb
Y     A           ccc    ddd
```

I am trying to run query joining table_1 and table_2 with target_id, and get JSON similar to followings (using Java)

```
[{"id": 1, "name"="John", "url": "example.org", 
"target": [{"id1":"X", "col1": ...}, {"id1":"Y", "col1": ...}]
}, 
{"id": 2, "name"="Jane", "url": "helloworld.com"}]
```

What we are doing right now is to iterate table_1, for each row, select from table_2, and add object into a list, and at the end serilize it to JSON.

Is that a better way instead of making nested sql in the loop in Oracle?

Comment: Use subqueries and [`JSON_ARRAYAGG`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/JSON_ARRAYAGG.html#GUID-6D56077D-78DE-4CC0-9498-225DDC42E054). Don't loop over data sets, do as much as possible in SQL with set processing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `JSON_ARRAYAGG` and `JSON_OBJECT`:

```sql
SELECT JSON_ARRAYAGG(
         JSON_OBJECT(
           KEY 'id'     VALUE t1.id,
           KEY 'name'   VALUE t1.name,
           KEY 'url'    VALUE t1.url,
           KEY 'target' VALUE t2.target ABSENT ON NULL
         )
       ) AS data
FROM   table_1 t1
       LEFT OUTER JOIN (
         SELECT target_id,
                JSON_ARRAYAGG(
                  JSON_OBJECT(
                    KEY 'id1' VALUE id1,
                    KEY 'col1' VALUE col1,
                    KEY 'col2' VALUE col2
                  )
                ) AS target
         FROM   table_2
         GROUP BY target_id
       ) t2
       ON t1.target_id = t2.target_id
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE  TABLE table_1 (ID, target_id, name, url) AS
SELECT 1, 'A', 'John', 'example.org' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'B', 'Jane', 'helloworld.com' FROM DUAL;

CREATE  TABLE table_2 (id1, target_id, col1, col2) AS
SELECT 'X', 'A', 'aaa', 'bbb' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'Y', 'A', 'ccc', 'ddd' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

| DATA |
| --- |
| [{"id":1,"name":"John","url":"example.org","target":[{"id1":"X","col1":"aaa","col2":"bbb"},{"id1":"Y","col1":"ccc","col2":"ddd"}]},{"id":2,"name":"Jane","url":"helloworld.com"}] |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/H__65_D1)

Answer (score 0):

table1:table2 = 1:N ?

```
SELECT AA.*, BB.* FROM table_1 AA
LEFT JOIN table_2 BB ON AA.target_id=BB.target_id
ORDER BY AA.id
```